# Is there any possibility to use JTA with Spring Framework 6 and Tomcat or Payara?

Tags: spring, hibernate, tomcat, jta, payara

Can you explain how to use Java Transaction API with pure Spring Framework on Payara or Tomcat server. I cant find any solution. There are several threads on Stack Overflow about using tools like Atomikos with Tomcat or a larger server like Payara, but I can't find anywhere how to do it.

I tried to use Payara server with Hibernate but always when i try to get EntityManager from PersistenceContext i get "java.lang.ClassCircularityError: org/hibernate/jpa/internal/enhance/EnhancingClassTransformerImpl$Entry" exception.